# Setting up domain with LAMP server

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, lamp

Not sure if this is the best forum so let me know and I'll delete it if so.

I've setup a LAMP server on Ubuntu 14.04 which works fine the issue is, right now I can only access it through the public IP. I currently have a domain registered to me, but I got it from Freehosting.com so it points to the website I made there when I need it to point to my personal server now. I've done quite a bit of googling on the issue and most articles I find detail how to go from one online hosting company to a different one which is not what I need.

From what I can understand I need to point the nameservers of my domain to my server's public IP, however when I log on to do that and set the IP address to mine I get an error that I'm using the same domain name and I noticed the default one has

```
ns1.freehosting.com
ns2.freehosting.com
```

I only know the basics of nameservers, but apparently I need two and I thought the company I register my domain through had the name servers, but it seems like I actually need 2 name servers myself to point toward my IP is this correct? If so could I use BIND on my same PC like here https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html or would I need a separate PC? I can't find much on how much resources name servers use, but I have a fairly weak PC(4gb ram ~3.4 ghz 4core amd cpu) so I'm not sure it would be able to handle all of that.

To summarize I'm trying to point a domain registered on freehosting.com to a LAMP server now. Thanks for the help and if there is any information left out that would be helpful let me know and I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit DNS records from your Freehosting account and make `A record` for your domain point to your IP address. No need to set-up bind or anything else by yourself.

If you're not sure how to do it or don't know place to manage your DNS then contact Freehosting support. You can start using other nameservers awell, e.g [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com)'s to manage your DNS

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I ended up using CloudFlare. Thanks!